# jQuery Replace with using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am working on a dynamic SharePoint 2010 form that utilizes jQuery to Show an image after a user selects a drop down.  The user selects the Name of a Calendar item in a SharePoint list and .replaceWith() inserts a div with a link to the correct image where a dummy input single line of text is located.  This works properly on the first object each time but because there is no post back, it will not cycle on the .change() event.  Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this.  Reloading the form would be a hassle with the SP design.

Here is some of the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var iCal1row = $("nobr:contains('Calendar 1 Image')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr');
    var iCal2row = $("nobr:contains('Calendar 2 Image')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr');
    var iCal1 = $("nobr:contains('Calendar 1 Image')").parent('h3').parent('td').next('td').children('span').find(':input');
    var iCal2 = $("nobr:contains('Calendar 2 Image')").parent('h3').parent('td').next('td').children('span').find(':input');

    $("select[title*='Calendar 2 Name']").change(function()
    {
        var Cal2Val = $("select[title*='Calendar 2 Name']").val();
        var Cal2img = ''

        switch(Cal2Val)
        {
            case "0":
                iCal2row.hide();
                break;

            case "1":   
                Cal2img = 'http://www.website.org/images/desk_n2556.jpg';
                iCal2row.show();
                iCal2.replaceWith('<div class="iCal2"><img src="' + Cal2img + '"/></div>');
                break;

            case "2":   
                Cal2img = 'http://www.website.org/images/desk_n20241.jpg';
                iCal2row.show();
                iCal2.replaceWith('<div class="iCal2"><img src="' +Cal2img + '"/></div>');
                break;
}

    }); 
});
```

Thanks so much for any insight

Comment: Does `select[title*='Calendar 2 Name']` match multiple elements?

Comment: No, the `select[title*='Calendar 2 Name']` matches only one Dropdown listed.

Comment: Even so, you should probably use `$(this).val()`, to avoid repeating the selector and be more efficient. Also, why use a partial match if you can do an exact match?

Comment: I don't understand the question, then. What do you mean by it won't cycle on the change event?

Comment: The change event fires when the user selects an option the first time.  Then when they change to another selection, the change event fires properly, but the replaceWith() does not change the <a> tag.  The only way I know to do this would be a post back, or a cookie to hold and repopulate the fields, but the use of this is limited in my current environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after you use `iCal2.replaceWith()`, the variable `iCal2` no longer refers to an element in the DOM. It still refers to the original SPAN, which has been removed from the DOM.

Re-assign the variable to refer to the new element:

```
iCal2.replaceWith(...);
iCal2 = $("nobr:contains('Calendar 2 Image')").parent('h3').parent('td').next('td').children('span').find(".Cal2");
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  DOM still has the iCal2 row, I tried the above code but it doesn't quite do what the issue is.  I may not hav been clear in my explanation.  The image appears and the row shows up when a user selects their option.  But when the person decides to select another option, the same image stays in place.  i have confirmed the variable changes by putting an alert at the start of the case and after `(alert("Value of Cal2img = " + Cal2img);` But since there is no page reload and the `<div>` has replaced the input, it just sits at the first image.  Hope this clarifies. Thank you!